# Use common axis limits across scatter plot matrix panels (lattice splom function)

Tags: r, lattice

If multiple variables are on the same scale, it can be nice to use the same axis limits for each panel of a matrix of scatterplots, to facilitate comparison. By default, `splom` uses the more space-efficient method of using scales defined by the range of each variable separately, and I cannot figure out how to override this. (I cannot get the `xlim` and `ylim` arguments to have any effect at all, so clearly I do not yet understand how the different arguments to `splom` interact.)

For example, all the `iris` measurements are in centimeters, so it would be reasonable to plot them all against each other with the same x and y limits if we wanted.
How would we extend the example on the `splom` help page?
Simplified version: `splom(~iris[1:4], groups = Species, data = iris)`

Comment: a bit crude but gets you there . `lims <- range(unlist(iris[1:4]))` . `splom(~iris[1:4], groups = Species, data = iris,       prepanel.limits=function(x) lims)`